# C# func<> applied to the object on left

Tags: c#, member, func

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use func (or a similar method) applied to the left object.
Ex.:

```
member1.MyFunction()
```

Here's a simplified context of usage. We got ClassA which contains a List of ClassB and a method to sum up the elements of classB. And classB possess two attribute memberX and memberY which are of double type. The func is to be use to choose which member of ClassB we'd like to sum.

I've got an error in the line where I write

```
theSum += TheList[i].TheFunction();
```

The error is:

> CS1061  C# does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone knows a workaround? My research could'not lead me to anything applied to the left side of the generic function.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public List<ClassB> TheList;
    public ClassA()
    {
        ClassB m1 = new ClassB(1, 2);
        ClassB m2 = new ClassB(1, 2);
        ClassB m3 = new ClassB(1, 2);
        TheList= new List<ClassB>() { m1, m2, m3 };
    }
    private double CalculateSum(Func<double> TheFunction)
    {
        double theSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < TheList.Count(); i++)
        {
            theSum += TheList[i].TheFunction();
            // I'd like to use the previous line instead of having to write
            // a function for both of the following.
            // theSum += TheList[i].GetMember1();
            // theSum += TheList[i].GetMember2();
        }
        return theSum;
    }
}
public class ClassB
{
    private double memberX;
    private double memberY;
    public ClassB(double x, double y)
    {
        memberX = x;
        memberY = y;
    }
       
    public double GetMember1() { return memberX; }
    public double GetMember2() { return memberY; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
private double calculateSum(Func<ClassB, double> aFunction)
{
    double theSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count(); i++)
    {
        theSum += aFunction(aList[i]);
    }

    return theSum;
}
```

**Update**

If you really want to apply the func to the object to its left, then you could define an extension method.

```
public static class ClassBExtensions
{
    public static double Sum(this ClassB arg, Func<ClassB, double> func)
    {
        return func(arg);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this

```
Func<ClassB, double> func = null; // define your func here
for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count(); i++)
    {
        theSum += aList[i].Sum(func);
     }
 return theSum;
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but seeing the answers (and the search results) I believe there is no other way of using Func<> or any other similar methods.

Comment: See my update if you want to apply the func to the object to its left.

Answer (score 3):

Well not with quite that syntax, but you can just use:

```
theSum += aFunction(aList[i]);
```

I suppose you *could* write an extension method for this, but the above is more idiomatic.

In fact, using LINQ to start with would be more idiomatic - your `calculateSum` method is already present in LINQ as `Sum`, so you could call:

```
double sum = aList.Sum(x => x.getMember1());
```

Of course more idiomatically, you'd use properties instead of methods:

```
double sum = aList.Sum(x => Member1);
```

Also for idiom, you'd make sure that any methods you *do* have follow .NET naming conventions, starting with a capital letter. I *strongly* advise you to start following naming conventions (even for throwaway demo code) immediately.

Comment: I feel this answer should really include the new definition of `aFunction` for that first line. With a `Func<double>` this isn't going to do anything except give the OP a different error to ask about.

Comment: I edited my post to get closer to the naming conventions. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want an method "on" `ClassB` that returns one of its values. (Whether `ClassB` should have such a method or not - it might simply be a part of the calculation and as such actually belonging to `ClassA` - is a different question.)

If you can change `ClassB`, simply add it there:

```
public class ClassB
{
    private double memberX;
    private double memberY;
    public ClassB(double x, double y)
    {
        memberX = x;
        memberY = y;
    }

    public double GetMember1() { return memberX; }
    public double GetMember2() { return memberY; }

    public double AFunction() 
    {
        bool condition = ...
        return condition ? memberX : memberY;
    }
}
```

I'm using the ternary operator `?:` here to save some spaces on `if/else`.

Now if you can *not* change `ClassB`, [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (as hinted in the `CS1061` error message) might help you:

```
public static class ClassBExtensions
{
    public double AFunction(this ClassB b)
    {
        bool condition = ...
        return condition ? b.GetMember1() : b.GetMember2();
    }
}
```

You can now simply call `.AFunction()` on any instance of type `ClassB` as if the method was originally declared there. Note that extension methods only have access to publicly accessible fields.

You also might want to look into [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) which allow to reduce your `ClassB` definition to:

```
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB(double x, double y)
    {
        MemberX = x;
        MemberY = y;
    }

    public double Member1 { get; }
    public double Member2 { get; }

    /*
    public double AFunction() 
    {
        bool condition = ...
        return condition ? Member1 : Member2;
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: I'm definitely gonna reduce my class definition as suggested. I wasn't aware of the existence of extensions methods, it's a good read. AsI can change Class B, your suggestion might be good for me, but I still have to see if it's best for my non-simplified application.